# Find $\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho^3}$ where $\rho$ is a non trivial zero of zeta function

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I am reading the Equivalents of Riemann Hypothesis: Arithmetic Equivalents pg. 35 Lemma 2.10. If $\rho$ is a non trivial zero of the Riemann Zeta function then,
$\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho}=1+\frac{\gamma}{2}-\frac{1}{2} 
     log  \ 4\pi$

I want to know what is $\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho^3}$?. Please provide a reference if possible..

Answer (score 1):

Edit I thought it was $\sum \rho^{-2}$, for $\sum \rho^{-3}$ it works the same way

$$\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{s^3\zeta(s)}ds=0$$
This is also equal to

$$\int_{2-i\infty\to 2+i\infty\to -\infty\to 2-i\infty} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{s^3\zeta(s)}ds$$
Then apply the residue theorem, you'll get your series plus the residue at $1$, the residue at $0$ and the sum of the residues at the trivial zeros which is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(-2n)^3}$

The residue at $0$ depends on known constants plus $\zeta'(0),\zeta''(0),\zeta'''(0)$, by the functional equation those relate to the [Laurent coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) of $\zeta(s)$ at $s=1$

Comment: so what is the sum? I could not get you .Sorry.

Comment: What do you not understand ?

Comment: the integral. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: What do you not understand in which integral ?

Comment: The first integral which is equal to 0. Please provide a reference

Comment: The limit as $a\to +\infty$ is $0$, and by Cauchy integral theorem $\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{s^3\zeta(s)}ds$ doesn't depend on $a>1$

Comment: How does this integral gives the required sum over non trivial zeros??

Comment: Do you understand what $\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}f(s)ds$ means ? A contour integral, of an analytic (meromorphic) function. This topic is called complex-analysis. Then it is a contour integral along a closed loop, to which we can apply the residue theorem.

Comment: Yes i understand but what is the expression for $\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho^n} ,  n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Apply the residue theorem ! $0=\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{s^3\zeta(s)}ds=\int_{2-i\infty\to 2+i\infty\to -\infty\to 2-i\infty} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{s^3\zeta(s)}ds$ $=2i\pi (\sum_\rho Res(\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s^3\zeta(s)},\rho)+\sum_{m\le -1}  Res(\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s^3\zeta(s)},m))$

Comment: what is the expression for $\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho^n}?$

Comment: I cannot guess what you are thinking to. It is obvious that it works the same way for all $n\ge 2$, so there is probably something you don't understand in the case $n=3$, for example how to compute the residues.

Comment: please give me a closed form for $\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho^n}$?